# Save/customize the file browser interface

Tags: interface, customization, file-browser

Everytime I open the file browser interface, the directory windows on the left are arranged as default. Even if I switch Recent on top of System and minimize System, the next time I open the interface, it's gone and back to default and I have to scroll down all the way to select the ones I need.

Is there any way to save the interface disposition? Or to force its look with some script?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could store your projects in individual files saved to your desktop?

Comment: I'd still have the System and Volumes windows to browse, so I don't see how it would help.